# What happened about the swap used?

Tags: linux, swap

Q：Why is the used value of swap so large? Is there a error/bug/problem with the kernel?

env: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

```
[root@dc-hadoop203 ~]# free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           125        102         23          0          0         88
-/+ buffers/cache:         13        112 
Swap:           58 1717986918         58 
[root@dc-hadoop203 ~]# swapoff -a
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@dc-hadoop203 ~]# free -g   
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           125        102         23          0          0         88
-/+ buffers/cache:         13        112 
Swap:            0 1717986918
```